# Custom service application - proxy stopped

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Ive created a custom service app using samples from [Tony Bierman](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/index.php/2009/10/building-a-sharepoint-service-application-to-provide-auto-completion-services-for-ajax-enabled-rich-user-controls-%e2%80%93-part-1/) and [MS](http://blogs.msdn.com/sridhara/archive/2010/04/03/custom-service-applications-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).  I can see the application in central admin, I can create a new service app from it, the create page works, the manage page is blank and I don't have a properties page.  I havent yet tried using the beast, I just want to get the deployment and admin stuff working first.  It deploys ok and I can create an instance.

However, after creating it, I see the Service app has started but the app proxy is stopped.

I dont know if this is a problem or not but I cant find anywhere to start it.

Should I worry?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that yes, I do need to worry.  The problem was I had the proxy package feature receiver scoped to web rather farm. Took me  a week to find this :(